# Dependency injection is always null

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Im tryin to inject a interface with an implementation but it is always null.

I use the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the code

LoginServlet class

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login.do")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        User user = userDao.findByUsername("USERNAME");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(user.getName());
    }
}
```

UserDao interface

```
public interface UserDao {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserDaoImpl class

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("HEEEY");
        return user;
    }
}
```

And the user class

```
public class User {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I do not get this to work.. and do not understand why.

Comment: Where and how is your application deployed?

Comment: UserDaoImpl is not in the context. Maybe you can write annotation to UserDaoImpl

Comment: I deploy it in tomcat 

and this is my web.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>test</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are missing a beans.xml or you have no cdi library available. (Tomcat should have it so it is likely a missing beans.xml)

An empty file named beans.xml in the locations described by:

[Where should beans.xml be placed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991561/where-should-beans-xml-be-placed)

is enough.

Comment: I'm not using using the spring framework.. but is this also required for javax injections?

Comment: Depends on version of Tomcat, but any recent version should have it. Did adding a beans.xml change the behavior?

Comment: I dit create the `beans.xml` in my WEB-INF but it still is not working..
Do i need to add something in pom.xml file to build it? This is what i have in my beans.xml: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>`

Comment: depending on how you are building with maven it sould be in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF or src/main/resources/META-INF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Inject
UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    User user = userDaoImpl.findByUsername("USERNAME");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(user.getName());
}
```

I think, this should work.

Comment: You should inject on interfaces, and not on implementation classes.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@RequestScoped` annotation on `UserDaoImpl` class

```
@RequestScoped
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("HEEEY");
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ehh i tried this but it still is not working and giving me a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: and use the interface to get the implementation in LoginServlet

Comment: Yes this is wat i use `@Inject
    UserDao userDao;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your beans are not scanned by CDI scanner.
Add this empty `beans.xml` file under `src/main/resources/META_INF`

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>
```

this will activate the scanning.